# What Good is Sharing Security Keys along with Downloads

Tags: security, sha

Sometimes I see a list of keys along with a download that I believe are meant to verify if a downloaded file is legit. For example here

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/

There are SHA1 sums at the end of the download page.

I assume the process is, you download file, verify it using these sums. However, if someone hacked the page and installed a modified version of download files, wouldn't they change the SHA sums as well? Then what is the purpose of sharing the sums / keys along with downloads?

Comment: Well it can also be used to verify the integrity of the dl, check if your file wan't corrupted.

Comment: Also to verify authenticity of remote mirrors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"That they can also be used to verify the integrity of the dl, check if your file wan't corrupted, and to verify authenticity of remote mirrors" are good enough for me.

Comment: In the example you've given, it looks like the `SHA1SUMS` file has also been cryptographically signed using someone's GPG key, with the signature residing in `SHA1SUMS.gpg`. So you can verify the authenticity of the hashes using the public key, then use the hashes to verify the downloads. It might be possible to replace both downloads and hashes, but assuming the private key is secure and you reliably know beforehand whose public key to use for verification, it should be impossible for someone else to replace the downloads, the hashes *and* forge the signature for the hashes.